# Get OldValue of a property in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to get the old value of a property in the MVVM, when I want to save it.
I want to know the initial values of a selectedItem because I would like to
1- know if item was changed
2- update the table with a field UpdatedDate
3- if the price has changed, I would like to update another table for price history.

How can I do that

```
    public class ItemViewModel : ObjectBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> itms = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    private ObservableCollection<Item> _prevItems;



    private Item selectedItem;

    public Item SelectedItem
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return this.selectedItem;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        this.selectedItem= value;
                        this.RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");

                    }
                }
    #region SaveItem
    private void SaveItem(object obj)
        {
            if (this.items != _prevItems)
            {
                this.selectedItem.DateUpdated = this.DateUpdated;
                this.item.EditAsync(this.selectedItem );

            }
            else 
            {
                this.item.EditAsync(this.selectedItem );
            }

            this.LoadData();
          }
    #endregion
    #region Items
     private ObservableCollection<Item> items;

    public ObservableCollection<Item>  Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
        set 
        {
            this.items = value;
            itms = items;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Items"); 
        }
    } 
    #endregion          
    #region EditItem
    private void EditItem(object obj)
    {
        itms = items;
        _prevItems = itms;

    }
    #endregion          
}

public class ObjectBase : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{       
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #region RaisePropertyChanged
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));               
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Store a copy before it changes. You could just keep the last one in a private field `Item _prevSelectedItem;`, or you could have a private `List<Item> _selectedItemHistory`. It's just programming.

Comment: @EdPlunkett : when I click on edit, I can catch the old value of the collection (see Edit Item), I change the name of the ietem and click save, then I see that _prevItems has also changed, knowing that I have a breakpoint on Edit Item, and when I try to save the new data, the breakpoint stops only by save.

Comment: I have no idea what EditItems is supposed to do or who calls it. Is it a command execute method? What is it supposed to be doing? Why do you have an `itms` collection as well as `items`? What does any of that have to do with `SelectedValue`? Why are you setting `_prevItems` to the NEW value of `itms`?

Comment: @EdPlunkett: thank you for your reply. let me explain a bit my scenario: my screen contains a ListView of Items, 5 columns: 3 for attributes, and 2 for edit and delete.
when I select an item, and I click on edit (editItem command), the edit form appears below the listView. then I can change the name of the item, for example, and then I click save (save command).

Comment: Ok. And EditItem is meant to have something to do with that? Also remember I said "store a COPY". Storing another reference to the same altered object won't get you the old version.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: I did'nt understand what you mean by store a copy? Can you give more details? Ps. EditItem is intended only to show the edit form (changing a boolean property in the vm).

Comment: Google "copy an object C#"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly below can help

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> itms
{
get{ return _itms;}
set
{
if(value != _itms)
{
_prevItems = _itms;
_itms = value;
}

}
```

This will save the old item before updating it with new value